# Debugging the boot filesystem environment seen by syslinux?

Tags: c, linux, boot, syslinux

Hope it's OK to jot this down, even if I cannot accept answer immediately (and hope it's OK for SO - as there is a C patch below):

It seems I screwed up the hard disk on my desktop PC (`{DRDY err}`). So I wanted to run a bootable media to run `fsck`, but the CD on this desktop is broken, so I can only use USB flash. I have a couple of USB thumbdrives with Ubuntu and Suse - these start booting on the desktop; but during boot, udev tries to detect hard drives, and since the hard disk is screwed, it just loops there, and the respective OS never finishes booting.

So I tried to download [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download); I have this USB thumbdrive, on which I tried to install SystemRescueCD:

```
# lsusb with sudo, to retrieve all info
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 058f:6387 | grep -i 'id\|iManufacturer\|iProduct\|iSerial\|bInterface'
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Transcend JetFlash Flash Drive
  idVendor           0x058f Alcor Micro Corp.
  idProduct          0x6387 Transcend JetFlash Flash Drive
  iManufacturer           1 takeMS
  iProduct                2 Mem-drive Mini
  iSerial                 3 C5E7F0CC
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk (Zip)

# search by serial:
$ find /dev/disk/by-id/ -name '*C5E7F0CC*'
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_Mem-drive_Mini_C5E7F0CC-0:0-part1
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_Mem-drive_Mini_C5E7F0CC-0:0

# list and get device node
$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_Mem-drive_Mini_C5E7F0CC-0:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2013-03-25 20:37 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_Mem-drive_Mini_C5E7F0CC-0:0 -> ../../sdc
$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_Mem-drive_Mini_C5E7F0CC-0\:0-part1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2013-03-25 20:37 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_Mem-drive_Mini_C5E7F0CC-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdc1

# it is /dev/sdc - list disk info
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 2108 MB, 2108686336 bytes
94 heads, 29 sectors/track, 1510 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2726 * 512 = 1395712 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003e405

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1        1511     2059263+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I tried to use my Ubuntu 11.04 Natty netbook to image the thumbdrive - and I used both

- the recommended [usb_inst.sh installer](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick#Execute_the_installer); and
- I tried to use `unetbootin` (via `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`);

in both of these cases, when I try to boot the USB thumbdrive on the desktop, the boot procedure fails with:

```
SYSLINUX 4.02 debian-20101016 CHS Copyright (C) 1993-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot:
```

.... with prompt at boot. (In fact, `unetbootin` fails at "Verifying DMI Pool Data", before entering `syslinux` - probably because it is much older than the .iso I'm trying to image).

First I checked the md5 as mentioned in [No Default or UI Configuration Found!](http://www.sysresccd.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=3055)

```
$ md5sum ./systemrescuecd-x86-3.5.0.iso
48552b9e905872bd5061eb112b73ea20  ./systemrescuecd-x86-3.5.0.iso
```

... but it seems OK, as per [Sysresccd-versions](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-versions).

Then I tried to reformat the drive to FAT16 (via `sudo gparted /dev/sdc`); and repeated both `usb_inst.sh` and `unetbootin` methods - again no dice. Funny enough, in all of these cases, if I try to run the flash USB thumbdrive in the QEMU emulator:

```
# sudo apt-get install qemu
sudo qemu -hda /dev/sdc
```

... it boots fine - showing the syslinux menu and so on; however, boot always fails on the desktop.

Here I should mention, that I could write down the following from the boot screen of the problematic desktop PC:

```
Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG
AMDRS740 BIOS
```

It has a boot menu accessed via <kbd>F12</kbd>, and in the boot menu, among other options, these are for USB:

```
...
USB-FDD
USB-ZIP
USB-CDROM
USB-HDD
...
```

Typically, I choose USB-HDD - but I've tried the others; either the procedure freezes before even entering `syslinux` - or the boot fails as described above.

There is advice to rename directories/files manually from `isolinux` to `syslinux` ([Trying to boot from usb - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/128168)) - when I used `usb_inst.sh`, only `syslinux/isolinux.bin` would have to be renamed. There is also advice to copy `syslinux.cfg` to the root of the USB flash thumbdrive ([Cannot boot Live USB, Linux - Super User](https://superuser.com/a/182064/39752)). But still no improvements - `syslinux` is still complaining that it is missing the configuration file - which apparently is the `syslinux.cfg`.

Then I tried to look if it is possible to somehow "debug" syslinux; found [log tracing/debugging/trouble shooting in syslinux - The Syslinux Project - reboot.pro](http://reboot.pro/topic/15205-log-tracingdebuggingtrouble-shooting-in-syslinux/):

> > Do we have specific commands to trace or log syslinux?
>   Being open source, one is able to compile Syslinux and enable extra debugging output.

also [[SOLVED] Stuck on boot: Syslinux Problem [Archive] - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2020351.html): "_
Debugging syslinux is described at http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Development/Debugging , but effective debugging (if I recall correctly) requires recompiling it to add the debug hooks._". However, [Development/Debugging - Syslinux Wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Development/Debugging) talks about something called `bochs`; and I suspect that is to debug `syslinux` itself - not necessarily to "debug" (or query) the *environment* it is in.

Anyways, at last, I could see no way out but to get `syslinux` from source; basically, this was needed so it builds:

```
sudo apt-get install nasm
sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/boot/syslinux/syslinux.git syslinux-git
cd syslinux-git/
make OPTFLAGS+=-DDEBUG=1
```

Turns out, it isn't really clear how to enable such debugging, that will show what `syslinux` "sees" when plugged in a given computer; given that I do load into `syslinux` at boot, the problem is what does it see as a filesystem. I tried to enable the DEBUG environment variable as shown above (after adding `override OPTFLAGS :=` to the `Makefile`) - but that, in itself, generated no new messages during boot failure. I have used the following command to "burn" the USB thumbdrive (after unmounting it from the Gnome applet):

```
sudo ./linux/syslinux --stupid --directory /syslinux --install /dev/sdc1
```

... and I've tried both with `stupid` and without (and both for the source-built version, and the one from the Ubuntu package repositories for Natty).

Grepping through the source, I realized there is something called `rosh` ([Read-Only SHell](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Read-Only_SHell(rosh.c32))) - however, that compiles as a `rosh.c32` - and one is supposed to have it as a boot kernel option in `syslinux.cfg` - which, as noted, I cannot load. So `rosh.c32` is unfortunately not much help for my problem.

However, given that `rosh` implements the `ls` command, I tried to copy relevant portions into the code of `syslinux` - and trigger a `ls /` listing of the root when `syslinux` scans for the configuration file. With those changes, recorded in [syslinux-e40ba60-rosh-ls.patch](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/patch/syslinux-e40ba60-rosh-ls.patch); now I get the following when I boot:

```
SYSLINUX 4.06 CHS 5-ge40ba60* Copyright (C) 1993-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
Listing: "/"
rosh_ls_arg_dir 0 files found
Listing: "/syslinux"
Listing: ""
CurrentDirName: "/syslinux/"
confignamebuf: /syslinux/extlinux.conf; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /syslinux/syslinux.cfg; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /boot/syslinux/extlinux.conf; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /syslinux/extlinux.conf; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /syslinux/syslinux.cfg; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /extlinux.conf; realpath -1
confignamebuf: /syslinux.cfg; realpath -1
ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
```

Interestingly; for the root `/`, the `_ls` function at least returns "0 files"; the others ("/syslinux", and the empty string "") already fail at the `opendir` call - and so the `_ls` function doesn't even get called!

I would have thought that my slapstick copying of the `ls` function would not work as intended; but running the thumbdrive in `qemu` on netbook, does in fact provide a full listing of files - and given that at least for `/`, the function gets called and returns on the desktop - I'd suspect that it does indeed work.

However, that still doesn't solve my problem - *why* does `syslinux`, after boot, see 0 files under the root `/`? What else could I do to debug this problem? I wouldn't mind patching some C code into `syslinux` - but I just don't know what I should be looking for, that would point me to correct preparation of the USB thumbdrive for booting on the desktop machine...

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it to boot...

First, I noted there are alternative mbr's in the built git source as per [Mbr - Syslinux Wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Mbr) and [HowTos - Syslinux Wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/HowTos#How_to_Create_a_Bootable_USB%3a_For_Linux), so I tried both `mbr.bin` and `altmbr.bin` - `altmbr.bin` like this:

```
$ printf '\1' | cat mbr/altmbr.bin - | sudo dd bs=440 count=1 conv=notrunc iflag=fullblock of=/dev/sdc
```

... but that didn't help much.

Finally, I noted that `lsusb` says "bInterfaceProtocol  80 Bulk (Zip)"; and I remembered reading something about ZIP drives somewhere, so tried to look it up - and finally found this:

[syslinux/doc/usbkey.txt](http://www.syslinux.org/doc/usbkey.txt)

> The proper mode to boot a USB key drive in is "USB-HDD".  That is the
>   ONLY mode in which the C/H/S geometry encoded on the disk itself
>   doesn't have to match what the BIOS thinks it is.  Since geometry on
>   USB drives is completely arbitrary, and can vary from BIOS to BIOS,
>   this is the only mode which will work in general.
>
> Some BIOSes have been reported (in particular, certain versions of the
>   Award BIOS) that cannot boot USB keys in "USB-HDD" mode.  This is a
>   very serious BIOS bug, but it is unfortunately rather typical of the
>   kind of quality we're seeing out of major BIOS vendors these days.  On
>   these BIOSes, you're generally stuck booting them in USB-ZIP mode.
>
> THIS MEANS THE FILESYSTEM IMAGE ON THE DISK HAS TO HAVE A CORRECT
>   ZIPDRIVE-COMPATIBLE GEOMETRY.
>
> ....
>
> The script "mkdiskimage" which is supplied with the syslinux
>   distribution can be used to initialize USB keys in a Zip-like fashion.
>   To do that, calculate the correct number of cylinders (31 in the
>   example above), and, if your USB key is /dev/sda (CHECK THE KERNEL
>   MESSAGES CAREFULLY - IF YOU ENTER THE WRONG DISK DRIVE IT CANNOT BE
>   RECOVERED), run:
>
> mkdiskimage -4 /dev/sda 0 64 32
>
> (The 0 means automatically determine the size of the device, and -4
>   means mimic a zipdisk by using partition 4.)

So, as recommended there, first I find the number of cylinders for my thumbdrive:

```
$ grep 512-byte /var/log/syslog | tail -n 1
Mar 25 22:33:34 mypc kernel: [50884.608687] sd 45:0:0:0: [sdc] 4118528 512-byte logical blocks: (2.10 GB/1.96 GiB)

# get number of cylinders:
$ wcalc '4118528/(64*32)' 
= 2011
```

... then I continue with `mkdiskimage`. After that was done, I tried `usb_inst.sh` again - and realized that it will overwrite the partition 4 that `mkdiskimage` made, and make a partition 1 for itself instead. That means, one should copy those files fron `usb_inst.sh` in a backup elsewhere, then run `mkdiskimage` - then finally copy the backed up files back to thumbdrive again; here is a command line log:

```
# mkdiskimage is present in syslinux-git:
$ ./utils/mkdiskimage 
Usage: ./utils/mkdiskimage [-doFMz4][-i id] file c h s (max: 1024 256 63)
....

# ... but also in Debian/Ubuntu packaging of syslinux
$ mkdiskimage -4 /dev/sdc 0 64 32
/usr/bin/mkdiskimage: /dev/sdc: don't know how to determine the size of this device

# use sudo - note this command takes a while to complete:
$ sudo mkdiskimage -4 /dev/sdc 0 64 32
Warning: more than 1024 cylinders (2011).
Not all BIOSes will be able to boot this device.

$ ls /dev/sdc*
/dev/sdc  /dev/sdc4

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 2108 MB, 2108686336 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 2011 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x866262cc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc4   *           1        2011     2059248    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)

# (make sure umounted / ejected)

# cd to usb_inst.sh directory; and 
# run usb_inst.sh for /dev/sdc; note it will:
# write MBR and "Creating filesystem on /dev/sdc1..."
# and "installing boot loader on /dev/sdc1";
# regardless of the previous setup on partition 4:
sudo bash ./usb_inst.sh  

# now no more partition 4:
$ ls /dev/sdc*
/dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1

# ( mount /dev/sdc1 via disk applet )
$ rsync -a /media/SYSRESC /media/backup/

# ... duhh...  - again now

# ( umount/eject via disk applet )

$ sudo mkdiskimage -4 /dev/sdc 0 64 32
Warning: more than 1024 cylinders (2011).
Not all BIOSes will be able to boot this device.

$ sudo ./linux/syslinux --install /dev/sdc4

# ( mount via disk applet )

$ rsync -a /media/backup/SYSRESC/ /media/31A8-40E9/
$ sudo qemu -hda /dev/sdc  # works 

# ( umount/eject via disk applet )

# boot on desktop - works! loads rescue64 and initram.igz...
```

The interesting thing is - even if there is the warning "Not all BIOSes will be able to boot this device."; somehow this problematic BIOS loads this thumbdrive without a problem (and the `_ls` function above lists fine). Also interesting - here I choose the USB-HDD boot option (not the USB-ZIP) and it still works ?!

So, as a partial answer - I guess the way to debug this, would be for syslinux to somehow write on the thumbdrive the CHS geometry it sees during the syslinux installation; and on boot, to query the BIOS (I guess) about which CHS geometry the BIOS sees - and then dump these two geometries to screen; if there is a mismatch, then it is likely one should run `mkdiskimage` (*unfortunately, I wouldn't know how to code that into `syslinux`*)

---

Going back to my original HDD problem - turns out *also* SystemRescueCD uses `udev` to probe for devices - and again the boot process cannot complete (even if I choose the boot option "all files to memory (docache)")... So I get messages like:

```
udevadm settle - timeout of 180 seconds reached, the event queue contains:
Activating dmraid (fake hardware raid) ...
Starting mdadm (linux software raid) ....
udevd[88] worker [91] unexpectedly returned with status 0x0100 ...
udevd[88] worker [91] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/.../sdb/sdb1'
```

So, I either find a Live USB distro which does *not* probe for disks using `udev` - or I better take this HDD out, toss it into a HDD USB enclosure, and try fsck it on another computer (hopefully I'll be able to blacklist this drive from `udev` on a running system)

---

Edit Aug 24 2013: Back to this problem, I thought I'd jot down few extra notes:

Since I cannot yet afford the time to fix this PC and its faulty drive, I've used this USB thumbdrive to boot multiple operating systems: PartedMagic and SliTaz did also encounter errors on the hard disk - but apparently use different drivers to access it (so the `DRDY ERR` loop didn't start), and they could finish booting relatively fast. Then I tried building a custom Ubuntu 12.04 image (using `ubuntu-builder`) - and this one ended up in a `DRDY ERR` loop, which may take more than 5 minutes to complete, before the OS finishes booting. I have posted more about this in [Bug #1216397 “
It should be possible to ignore (skip probing) a known bad disk partition at boot” : Bugs : “linux” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1216397).

There are a few interesting things in respect to `syslinux`, now that this USB thumbdrive is used to boot multiple operating systems. First of all, the thumbdrive is, still, first made bootable with `syslinux --install` while empty (which places a file `ldlinux.sys` in the partition's root) - which corresponds to the `mkdiskimage` step above; and only afterwards are files (like kernel images, and including `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg`) copied to it.

Now, I'd first build the CD image ISO in `ubuntu-builder`, and test it using VirtualBox (as `qemu` on my machine is way too slow for that). Once the ISO image was shown to work as expected, then only the files under its `casper` directory are relevant for the USB thumbdrive thus prepared; and they can be referenced through a boot menu entry in `syslinux.cfg`. So, I'd edit the `syslinux.cfg` on the thumbdrive, and copy the `casper` image files (e.g. `filesystem.squashfs`) to the thumbdrive - and test it with `qemu` as above. Once this `qemu` step passed, I'd move the USB thumbdrive on the target PC with the broken drive - and interestingly, here I might get `syslinux` boot failures of multiple sorts (during different boot stages):

- "`No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!`" (*or sometimes a "Bad <something> ..." message*), before the `syslinux` boot menu is shown - *even* if the debug, as above, would show that `syslinux` reads the filesystem on the thumbdrive correctly, and finds the `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` (which does have proper directives)!
- "`Invalid or corrupt kernel image`", once the `syslinux` menu is shown, and the new kernel image (Ubuntu) chosen - *even* if the other images (found previously on the thumb) boot fine on the broken drive PC; and the new image boots fine from thumb in `qemu` on a different machine!
- "`/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sr0: no medium found`", once the new (Ubuntu) image is chosen from `syslinux` menu, and it starts booting; this seems an Ubuntu specific message, appearing a few seconds after it starts booting. I still encounter it even if booting completes succesfully - when it's a problem, this message just loops repeatedly, not allowing the rest of the boot process to complete

It turns out, any of these can appear whenever I try to change and save the `syslinux.cfg` file on the thumbdrive; or when I make changes in the `casper` image files, and I `rsync` or copy them to the thumbdrive. Maybe the copying process (since it may change the sectors where the files are located on the thumb), "confuses" parts of the boot process - although, this shouldn't happen, since also the working procedure above starts from a blanked, `syslinux`'d thumbdrive, to which files are copied after; so I think this may point to failing sectors on the thumbdrive.

However, even in this state, the working procedure above seemed to be useful - because using it, I could recover the thumb back to a working state! In more detail, it goes like this:

- Keep a copy of the thumbdrive files somewhere on a different disk (e.g. `~/thumbcopy`) - but *without* the `ldlinux.sys` file.
- Whenever you want to make a change (to `syslinux.cfg` or to bootable image files) - make sure this change is saved in `~/thumbcopy` *first*
- Now, say I've changed some files on the bootable thumbdrive directly, and I encounter one of the errors above. Then:

  - First, delete all files *but* the `ldlinux.sys` on the thumbdrive, e.g.:

    ```
    rm -rf $(ls -I"ldlinux.sys" /media/31A8-40E9/)
    ```
  - Then, `rsync` or copy (`cp -arv ...`) the files in `~/thumbcopy` to the thumbdrive, e.g.:

    ```
    rsync -aP ~/thumbcopy/ /media/31A8-40E9/
    ```
  - Now, try boot the thumbdrive in the PC again - it usually boots fine!

I've encountered all three types of errors, because I'd often try to change/copy individual files directly in the thumbdrive: sometimes the change doesn't introduce a problem, so booting is fine - however, in many cases, it does introduce a problem. For some reason, using the above procedure I managed to recover the thumbdrive from either type of abovementioned problems - maybe it has to do with USB Flash delayed writes, maybe with USB Flash failing sectors, I cannot really tell... But in any case: deleting all files, and re-copying them in one go, does seem to be a worthwhile procedure to try in case of errors like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ancient post, but in case others stumble upon this, I'll add an answer anyway.

If you're struggling to get syslinux to boot, ROSH (Read-only Shell) can be useful, as you mentioned. To start ROSH, you can simply type `rosh` at the `boot:` prompt (if you do have a working graphical menu, press escape to drop back to the `boot:` prompt.

Inside the shell, you have some basic commands to look around in your environment. For more documentation, see https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Read-Only_SHell(rosh.c32)

Comment: This doesn't help if syslinux can't find stage 2 (i.e. just prints "Boot Error"), which is far more typical than other errors on old BIOSes, especially with USB disks.

Comment: Something more useful for those problems https://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/blob/HEAD:/diag/geodsp/README but mostly for syslinux 6.